# Github pages from subdirectory

Tags: github, github-pages

I created repo with JS projects. Inside repo there are separate folders named:
1 project...
2 project...
 
etc.
I would like to create few GitHub-page`s with these projects.
Its something like this guy, all nice sorted in main folder:
https://github.com/romeojeremiah/javascript-projects-for-beginners
and github-page to one of the project:
https://romeojeremiah.github.io/Pass-the-Message-Project/

Comment: That particular web page actually comes from this repository: https://github.com/romeojeremiah/Pass-the-Message-Project/ .

Comment: correct, and how we can move these repos to different folder named e.g. "projects"?